# ZED camera - makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, camera, stereo-3d

Is there a sample where we can include ZED libraries in a simple makefile instead of using CMake?

I am a building a makefile and I am trying to include the ZED libraries, but I get 'not found' errors:

```
 EXTERNAL_CFLAGS += $(shell pkg-config --cflags zed)
 EXTERNAL_LIBS += $(shell pkg-config --libs zed)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by adding a .pc file in the pkconfig folder